# Problem extending UIButton for iOS

Tags: uibutton, subclass

I trying to extend UIButton but I keep getting a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS", inside the initializer of ColorButton's implementation file.

Header of ColorButton.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface ColorButton : UIButton {
    UIImage * originalImage;
}

@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * buttonName;

-(id) initButtonWithName:(NSString *) color;
-(void) setOriginalImage;
-(void) setImage:(UIImage *) image;
@end
```

ColorButton Implementation

```
#import "ColorButton.h"

@implementation ColorButton

@synthesize buttonName;

-(id) initButtonWithName:(NSString *) color {
    if ((self = (ColorButton *)[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom])) {
        buttonName = color;
        [self setTitle:buttonName forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //This is the line of the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.
        [self setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForDevice:color] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // This line gets the error too. If I comment the line before it out.
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIImage *) backgroundImageForDevice:(NSString *) color {
        color = [color stringByAppendingString:@"Bubble"];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"] ||[[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"]) {
        color = [color stringByAppendingString:@"-iPad"];
    }
    color = [color stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    return [UIImage imageNamed:color];
}

-(void) setOriginalImage {
    [self setBackgroundImage:originalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void) setImage:(UIImage *) image {
    [self setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not cast a `UIButton *` instance to a `ColorButton *` type.

You have to remember that you `ColorButton` inherits from `UIButton` and not the other way, this means that every instance of `ColorButton` is a `UIButton` by definition, but the opposite is not true.

Here is another thread that has the **exact** same issue :)

[objective C: Buttons created from subclass of UIButton class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443639/objective-c-buttons-created-from-subclass-of-uibutton-class-not-working/6443663#6443663)