# How do I display the title of a UIButton when overriding it's drawRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do I draw the title of a `UIButton` when subclassing it?
I need to subclass the `UIButton` class because of a custom `drawRect` method for drawing the button.

I believe that I have to draw the title inside the `drawRect` method, do I see that correctly?

Comment: Or just call `[super drawRect:]`...

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443639/objective-c-buttons-created-from-subclass-of-uibutton-class-not-working – it is quite tricky to subclass a UIButton to override drawing.

Comment: whats the ‘[super drawRect:]‘ method suppose to do? is it suppose to draw the title? (Of course i set the title with ‘self.titleLabel.text = titleName‘

Comment: @ChristopherScottyWittlinger [super drawRect:] is the drawRect behaviour of the (non-subclassed) UIButton class, so since the normal UIButton draws the title for you, that functionality would be in [super drawRect:]

Comment: @yuf a button is composed of several views, the text isn't necessarily drawn by drawRect.

Comment: if its not done by `[super drawRect:]` what do I have to do? I tried everything...

Comment: @jrturton I see, I was just trying to explaining why that would be something to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better (and advised by Apple) not to subclass UIButton if you can. Most custom appearances can be achieved by setting a background image to a standard "custom" button. This way you still get the functionality of resizing, the label, the image etc. without needing to subclass. A button has a background image, an image and a title label - how and by what these components are drawn is not publicly available.

If the image is derived at run time, you can still use the above technique, but draw in a new graphics context, extract the image and use that instead.

If you really must use a drawRect method, I'd subclass UIControl rather than UIButton.

Comment: Okay so I should do the custom drawings in a UIImage and then set this as the background?

Comment: I have written about something very similar here : http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2012/12/09/subtle-ui-texture-in-code/

Comment: `It is better (and advised by Apple) not to subclass UIButton` - can you show any place where they are saying something like that? Even I would say that there are some small tips for subclassing in UIButton documentation.

Comment: @lupatus it was mentioned on one of the WWDC 2012 videos, I can't remember which one though.