# Is there a way to "capture" all the UIButton taps inside an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, swizzling

I want to be able to track what buttons my users are tapping.
Is there a way to "capture" or "log" all the button taps inside my app?

I was thinking about method swizzling but I really rather not get into that.

Answer (score 1):

Aspect Programming may help you. Have a look at this library :

https://github.com/steipete/Aspects

Basically you do something like :

```
[UIButton aspect_hookSelector:@selector(whateverSelectorYouWantToHookOn:) 
                  withOptions:AspectPositionAfter 
                   usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo) {
   NSLog(@"UIButton called");
} 
error:NULL];
```

Have a look on the AspectInfo for more information on the instance called.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons can have multiple actions attached to them. You could always add a logging action to each of your buttons. The action method receives the sender, so you could log information about the button that was tapped.

Comment: I want to do something more "general" that will affect all the buttons in my app without having to add code to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIButton to add logging.  The accepted answer on

[objective C: Buttons created from subclass of UIButton class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443639/objective-c-buttons-created-from-subclass-of-uibutton-class-not-working)

has a good explanation on why this is one of the few instances that subclassing may be useful.

Basically UIButton inherits from UIControl and [UIControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) states

> Subclassing Notes You may want to extend a UIControl subclass for either of two reasons:
>
> To observe or modify the dispatch of action messages to targets for particular events
>   To provide custom tracking behavior (for example, to change the highlight appearance)